# Latin phrase meaning "this is the end of the road, and of the map"

Tags: idiom

Somewhere I encountered a phrase, in print or electronically I don't remember, which I took to mean, "this is the end of the road, and of the map". I seem to recall the phrase in Latin being (and I apologize in advance for this mess, I know it is incorrect) something like "hic finis viatiquae; et chartae". Please overlook the grammar mistakes here.

A web search for those words, or the English version, or variations of them, didn't find anything. I had assumed that the phrase was some idiom or quotation, but wasn't able to find a source for it.

Can someone provide a translation of the English phrase at least, or better still provide a Latin original?

Answer (score 2):

> **Brundisium longae finis chartaeque viaeque est.**

is the last line (104) of Horatius' [*Satyrarum Libri 1.5*](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0062), also known as **Iter quoddam suum Roma Brundusium usque singulari cum festivitate describit**.

According to [this abstract](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/255852097_Horace%27s_Material_chartae), *charta* with Horace does not mean map.

> Horace is drawn to the Greek loanword charta and uses it on thirteen
> occasions to refer to writing material, often his own.
> (...)
> At the end of Horace’s iter Brundisinum, the narrator’s Epicurean
> excursus is cut short by an announcement that he has run out of paper

If you want to see the journey from Roma to Brundisium on a map, have a look at this [site](https://omnesviae.org/en/#!iter_roma_brundisium)